# Where is our canonical answer to questions about normality of residuals and inference?

Tags: discussion, search

We get questions about the normality of residuals from models, e.g., [Dependent variable - bimodal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/368313/1352) Often, as in this example, it turns out that the OP wants to perform inference on model parameters and believes that residuals need to be normally distributed for inference to be valid.

I would have expected to find a highly voted question in the [normality-assumption](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normality-assumption) tag that I could use to VTC as a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Where is our canonical answer to questions about normality of residuals and inference?

Comment: Look through [these search results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=assumption*%20residual*%20normal*%20score%3a1%20answers%3a1%20-logistic).

Comment: @whuber: your search-fu leaves me speechless.

Comment: Here is another search I have found useful for locating **already used** targets:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=assumption*+residual*+normal*+++-logistic+duplicate%3Ayes   it is indirect, a direct way for searching for already used targets would be useful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[whuber](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/where-is-our-canonical-answer-to-questions-about-normality-of-residuals-and-infe?noredirect=1#comment16707_5447) pointed to [a very nice search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=assumption%2A%20residual%2A%20normal%2A%20score%3a1%20answers%3a1%20-logistic). It seems to me like the following thread is the most useful one for our purposes here: [Regression when the OLS residuals are not normally distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29731/1352).