# Profusion of threads on log transform - find candidates for FAQ tag

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

We regularly get questions about log transforming dependent variables, which [in some quarters appears to be seen as a magic silver bullet that solves all problems](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62093168#62093168), because apparently, "everything is normally distributed after log-transforming" (which, to be explicit, is *wrong*, and [not even useful](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5447/1352)). Here are a few useful prior threads in this vein (contributed by [User1865345](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62093277#62093277) and [mkt](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62093996#62093996)):

- [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18844/1352)
- [In linear regression, when is it appropriate to use the log of an independent variable instead of the actual values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/298/1352)
- [Interpretation of log transformed predictor and/or response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18480/1352)
- [Interpreting log-log regression with log(1+x) as independent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/576504/1352)

As in [this analogous question on imbalanced data](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/1352), it probably does not make sense to attempt to merge them into the One Question To Rule Them All As A Canonical Duplicate. However, I would propose that we collect a couple of useful threads on this topic here ([threads tagged both "data-transformation" and "logarithm" might be a good start](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transformation%2blogarithm?tab=Votes)) to use as duplicate targets, depending on the nuance of the newly posted question, and ask the moderators to slap the [faq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag on them.

Comment: There can be different types of issues with respect to log transforms of predictors versus outcomes. For predictors, there are things like dealing with 0 values and interpreting coefficients of transformed predictors. For outcomes, the OP has often jumped onto a log transformation without considering options like other variance-stabilizing transformations, Box-Cox, Gaussian GLM with log link, proportional-odds models, or nonparametric tests. Unfortunately, many threads cover both predictors and outcomes, making it harder for a new questioner to find just what's needed in a particular context.